# How to get Blender Compositor Image Node selected image name?

Tags: python, blender

In what way my Python script can get text string with name of an image, currently selected in Image Node? I guess is right to do using custom Node Label, but can't find any snippet, which describes method.

[image]

Script must work globally, even if no any node selected, if possible.

Comment: So you selected an image node in a NodeTree or NodeSocket and want to get the file name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps you out:

```
    nodes = material_slot.material.node_tree.nodes
    texture_node = nodes.get('Image Texture')


    if texture_node is None:
        texture_node = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeTexImage')
        #texture_node.image = image

    # Get the image name
    texture_name = texture_node.image.name
    # Set the node name / label to image name
    texture_node.name = texture_name
    texture_node.label = texture_name
```

if you want to get an existing node but you have multiple Texture Nodes, you could probably iterate trough all nodes and find all nodes of type "TEX_IMAGE" and set the name

EDIT:
I have seen you just added a picture, and you are not working with textures, sorry about that
Same principle as above goes for Image nodes though

```
bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].node_tree.nodes['Image'].image.name
```

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what i need - in your EDIT:
bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].node_tree.nodes['Image'].image.name

Comment: glad it worked out! I thought you want to programmatically rename the nodes bases on image name (thats why i suggested to iterate trough all the nodes) but if you know which node you want to target, then it's easier!

Answer (score 0):

You can find the compositor nodes in `bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes`, then loop through them and check if the type is `IMAGE`.

```
import bpy
for n in bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes:
    if n.type == 'IMAGE':
        # check that there is an image selected
        if n.image is not None:
            print(n.image.name)
```

If you only want an image node that is selected, add `if n.select:`